# C2326 function cannot access 'bar' when defining a lambda inside a local class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++11, compiler-errors

I have hit some strange compiler error involving local classes and lambdas. I have narrowed it down to the following example:

```
int main()
{
    class test {
        void foo(int bar) {
            auto lambda = [=] (int) { return bar; };
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

And VS10 says:

> error C2326: 'void main::test::foo(int)' : function cannot access 'bar'

Are there any limitations on using lambdas in local classes or is this a bug in the compiler?

Thanks four your help.

Comment: Someone once said: "When you think you have found a bug in the compiler, 99% of the time it is your fault. The remaining 1% of the time, it is also your fault." All jokes aside, with an example as simple as this, it is probably not a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @Markus, that's true for old a tried features of the language, in lambda expressions over VS10 I think it's closer to 80%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this happens in VS10 only when the class is defined in a function and the lambda accepts a parameter. 
No such problems appear in g++.

I believe this is indeed a bug, if you open a defect please link to it here so we can follow up on it (otherwise let me know and I'll open a defect).

Comment: Bug report can be found here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643697/c2326-function-cannot-access-bar-when-defining-a-lambda-inside-a-local-class#details

Answer (score 0):

And have you tried

```
int main()
{
    class test {
        void foo(int bar) {
            auto lambda = [bar] (int) { return bar; };
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe implementation of lambdas in VS10 is not complete, because your example works fine on g++4.5 - http://www.ideone.com/5xQpz

Comment: Pity. I don't have VS installed, so it was just a guess.